# Change style(color) Linear Progress Bar/ Material UI / Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

```
 <LinearProgress style={{barColorPrimary: "red"}}" value={Number(campanha.Percentual)} />
```

How can I change the barColorPrimary of the bar? I need to use style like in code.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the withStyles() higher-order component to inject custom styles.

Take a look at the example for the LinearProgress here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kwvb1?file=/demo.tsx (we override barColorPrimary for the bar color and colorPrimary for the background).

More info about customizing components in Material UI can be found here: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this..

```html
const CustomLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)(({ datatype }) => ({
  height: 6,
  borderRadius: 5,
  [`&.${linearProgressClasses.colorPrimary}`]: {
    backgroundColor: 'light gray',
  },
  [`& .${linearProgressClasses.bar}`]: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor:
      datatype === 'finished'
        ? 'green'
        : 'blue',
  },
}));


return (
      <CustomLinearProgress
        datatype="finished"
        variant="determinate"
        value={50}
      />
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way.
You can use `sx` prop.

```
<LinearProgress color="primary" variant={variant} sx={{'&::before': {color: 'red !important'}}} />
```

It is for v5 of MUI.